# Passing AND operation on a single column in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How to do I pass AND operation in SQL query? Here is my query:

```
select 
    distinct slr_product.seller_id, 
    slr_product.name,
    slr_product.price, 
    slr_seller.name 
from 
    slr_product join slr_seller 
where slr_product.seller_id = slr_seller.id 
and  slr_product.name in (
        "WEIL FELIX TEST*Proteus Antigen OX19, OX2 & OXK",
        "WIDAL TUBE AGGLUTINATION TEST",
        "ZINC, SERUM / PLASMA"
        )
```

I got results like this: 
          http://postimg.org/image/dhh57uzjn/

Also I tried `AND` operation instead on `IN` operator, but I got no result. I want to display **seller id** based on the **product name**, having these 3 products names. Here `seller_id = 33` having these products. I am using MYSQL.

Comment: Do you want to add your sample data and expected results?

Comment: If you only want results where the seller has all three products you will either need to do 3 subqueries or 3 joins, or some more complicated logic with CTEs or NOT EXISTS()

Comment: No, an AND wouldn't work, because `name` can not be two values at the same time (barring case-insensitivity). "AND X in (A, B, C)" is equivalent to "AND (X = A OR X= B OR X=C)". Also, why put the join condition (slr_product.seller_id = slr_seller.id) in the WHERE instead of in the JOINs ON?

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can get those seller_id who has all three product

```
Select slr_seller.seller_id,slr_seller.saler_name
From slr_seller
Where seller_id IN 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT seller_id 
    FROM slr_product 
    WHERE slr_product.name in ( 'WEIL FELIX TEST*Proteus Antigen OX19, OX2 & OXK',
                                'WIDAL TUBE AGGLUTINATION TEST',
                                'ZINC, SERUM / PLASMA') 
    GROUP BY seller_id 
    HAVING count(DISTINCT slr_product.name) = 3   //number of product 
    )
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/529d8/1)

[Updated SQlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de44fd/2)

EDIT:- With Product Name

```
Select DISTINCT slr_seller.seller_id,slr_seller.saler_name, slr_product.name
From slr_seller join slr_product ON slr_product.seller_id = slr_seller.seller_id
Where slr_seller.seller_id IN (
SELECT DISTINCT seller_id 
FROM slr_product 
WHERE slr_product.name in ( 'WEIL FELIX TEST*Proteus Antigen OX19, OX2 & OXK',
                            'WIDAL TUBE AGGLUTINATION TEST',
                            'ZINC, SERUM / PLASMA') 
GROUP BY seller_id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT slr_product.name) = 3  )
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de44fd/10)

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/n4vjm4is7/  but got result like that with out having clause... and also tried with having clause displyed no result.

Comment: Can you create sample sqlfiddle, or give us your sample data with table structure

Comment: @ srinu t:- I create sqlfiddle (SEE SQLFIDDLE link in Answer), you can check it is working..

Comment: Actually i wanted to display seller_id and name both. but here i add name result displaying only single record

Comment: Now sql query is modified to get seller_id and saler_name

Comment: If the `(seller_id,name)` tuple isn't guaranteed to be unique, this could return inaccurate results.  To have this work even when `name` could be duplicated, we could use **`HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT slr_product.name) = 3`**

Comment: is there any way to display product name also?

Comment: @ srinu t:-  see edit in answer to get Product name also, now you get three different rows for each seller_id as each seller has three product

Answer (score 0):

There are several query patterns that will return the specified result.

One option is to use `EXISTS` predicate with correlated subqueries. I think this is the easiest to understand, though it's a bit unwieldy for a large list of values; and it's difficult to extend this approach to handle "two out of three" type queries. And this is not usually the best performer, other options usually perform better.

With all those caveats, as a demonstration of this approach, just append to the existing query in the question:

```
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM slr_product p1
                 WHERE p1.seller_id = slr_seller.id
                   AND p1.name = 'WEIL FELIX TEST*Proteus Antigen OX19, OX2 & OXK'
              )
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM slr_product p2
                 WHERE p2.seller_id = slr_seller.id
                   AND p2.name = 'WIDAL TUBE AGGLUTINATION TEST'
              )
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM slr_product p3
                 WHERE p3.seller_id = slr_seller.id
                   AND p3.name = 'ZINC, SERUM / PLASMA'
              )
```

It's also possible to get a "count" of the products in the list for the seller,  and then filter on that. The correlated subquery is going to be executed for each row returned by the outer query, so this is also not usually the best performer, but this can be extended to check "2 out of 3". Just append this to the end of the existing query in the question:

```
   AND 3 = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.name)
               FROM slr_product p
              WHERE p.seller_id = slr_seller.id
                AND p.name IN ( 'WEIL FELIX TEST*Proteus Antigen OX19, OX2 & OXK'
                              , 'WIDAL TUBE AGGLUTINATION TEST'
                              , 'ZINC, SERUM / PLASMA'
                              )
           )
```

We can sometimes get better performance by running a subquery as an inline view, to return a set of rows, and then perform a JOIN operation to that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.seller_id
     , p.name
     , p.price
     , s.name 
  FROM slr_product p
  JOIN slr_seller s
    ON s.id = p.seller_id
    -- inline view to return seller_id that sell all three products
  JOIN ( SELECT r.seller_id
           FROM slr_product r
          WHERE r.name IN ( 'WEIL FELIX TEST*Proteus Antigen OX19, OX2 & OXK'
                          , 'WIDAL TUBE AGGLUTINATION TEST'
                          , 'ZINC, SERUM / PLASMA'
                          ) 
          GROUP BY r.seller_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.name) = 3
       ) q
    -- only return seller_id that sell all three products
    ON q.seller_id = p.seller_id
 WHERE p.name in ( 'WEIL FELIX TEST*Proteus Antigen OX19, OX2 & OXK'
                 , 'WIDAL TUBE AGGLUTINATION TEST'
                 , 'ZINC, SERUM / PLASMA'
                 )
```